# Aggregate and Count Items in a Result from MongoDB using pymongo & Flask

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I am trying to return a simple JSON result from MongoDB using pymongo in a Flask environment. Here's what I am doing:

```
def myResults():
    myCollection = db["my_data"]
    results = list(myCollection.find({},{"ID":1,"Response":1,"_id":0}))
    return jsonify(results=results)
```

When I do this, I get the following result. FYI `"ID"` is basically a made-up unique identifier.

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "ID": 1, 
      "Response": "A"
    }, 
    {
      "ID": 4, 
      "Response": "B"
    }, 
    {
      "ID": 3, 
      "Response": "A"
    },
  ]
} // and so on...
```

**I want to aggregate all the responses for a particular ID and show the count. Something that would look like this I guess (or if there's a better way):**

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "ID": 1, 
      "A": 2,
      "B": 1,
      "C": 5,
      "Total": 8
    }, 
    {
      "ID": 4, 
      "A": 0,
      "B": 5,
      "C": 18,
      "Total": 23
    }, 
    {
      "ID": 3, 
      "A": 12,
      "B": 6,
      "C": 8,
      "Total": 26
    },
  ]
}
```

Someone on StackOverflow recommend using `aggregate()`. But it's not really working for me.

```
allResults = surveyCollection.aggregate([
    {"$unwind": result }, 
    {"$group": {"_id": result.ID, "A": {"$sum": 1}, "B": {"$sum": 1}}},
    {"$group": {"_id": None, "result": {"$push": {"ID": "$ID", "A": "$A", "B": "$B"}}}}
])

return jsonify(allResults)
```

I get an error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ID'`.

Is there no simpler method by using just `find()` or `count()`?

Comment: Find() returns a cursor with all data collected in query, its simple command, you just iterate it and get information. Are you doing that?

Comment: @Urbester Yes I've used `find()` in the past to iterate and get the information I want, but I was wondering if somehow I could attach `count()` in order to solve the problem above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aggregation framework refers to all field names with a `$` prefix. This is not "python" code, but "aggregation pipeline" operations, such it's just a data structure to be translated into BSON.

```
allResults = surveyCollection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "ID": "$ID",
            "type": "$Response"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 },
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.ID",
        "A": { "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$_id.type", "A" ]}, "$count", 0 ] } },
        "B": { "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$_id.type", "B" ]}, "$count", 0 ] } },
        "C": { "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$_id.type", "C" ]}, "$count", 0 ] } },
        "Total": { "$sum": "$count" }
    }}
])

return jsonify(allResults)
```

This produces on the three documents you gave us, this result:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "A" : 1, "B" : 0, "C" : 0, "Total" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 4, "A" : 0, "B" : 1, "C" : 0, "Total" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 3, "A" : 1, "B" : 0, "C" : 0, "Total" : 1 }
```

So you started to do the right thing on the end, but got a bit off track in the middle.

What you **cannot** do here is "dynanically" create fields in the aggregation framework, so you need to specify all of the required "properties" and test with the conditions as shown. If you cannot live with that, then you need mapReduce for this format. Personally I would do this which is simpler:

```
allResults = surveyCollection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "ID": "$ID",
            "type": "$Response"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.ID",
        "results": { 
          "$push": {
            "type": "$_id.type", 
            "count": "$count"
          }
        },
        "Total": { "$sum": "$count" }
    }}
])

return jsonify(allResults)
```

Different output format, but the same basic information and simple:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "results" : [ { "type" : "A", "count" : 1 } ], "Total" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 4, "results" : [ { "type" : "B", "count" : 1 } ], "Total" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 3, "results" : [ { "type" : "A", "count" : 1 } ], "Total" : 1 }
```

BTW. This actually looks like it came from an aggregation result, so it might be time to revisit the code that created the source.

Comment: Thanks for the fixes. Makes sense. But unfortunately I am not seeing the result. I get this as my result `{"ok": 1.0,"result": []}`. Also the `:` after `"$add"` leads to a syntax error for some reason.

Comment: @mapr It would seem you are trying to follow on from a previous aggregation stage, and indeed each step seems to be asked as a separate question. This confuses the context for yourself and everyone else. I suggest adding in your previous "counting" stage in the group beforehand ( or you might have with different field names), making sure that you add all the fields as aggregation pipeline stages only receive in what is put out. Next time you ask, start from your source data. Doing this is stages will only misinform you, and can certainly be done better. But that is another question.

Comment: @mapr Which original question are you talking about? If I create a new collection ( single document actually ) with the data as show above then I get exactly the result you show with the query as above. As I said, you are clearly doing something different here.

Comment: @mapr Let's start again okay, done from the nearest source of information I can deem to be your original data.

Comment: You're probably doing this right, I believe you. But I'm not doing something different here. I'm double checking my work so I'll get back to you. I feel this line may be causing the problem even though I know it's correct: `results = list(myCollection.find({},{"ID":1,"Response":1,"_id":0}))`

Comment: @mapr Drop all the "result" prefix parts as well as the initial `$unwind`. Like I said, the data you present in your question looks like aggregation output from a MongoDB 2.4 or earlier version.

Comment: Ok. Just to be clarify I want to aggregate data, not disaggregate. The data I want to aggregate comes from running this line: `results = list(myCollection.find({},{"ID":1,"Response":1,"_id":0}))`

Comment: @mapr Really don't know how I can be clearer than what I have already said. Still edited again. Please only show your data in original form in future questions.

Comment: Now it is working. Perhaps I was a bit unclear initially. Thank you so much for your help throughout.

Answer (score 0):

Replace result.ID with "result.ID". Without the quotes python is going to look for the variable result.ID (which doesn't exist) instead of sending the server the literal string "result.ID".

Comment: This results in `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure`. I think the `$` needs to be there before `result` string.